# how to match vtk polydata and itk transforms

Tags: python, vtk, itk

I need to transform (rotation for now) an itk image and vtk polydata using the same transform matrix but I am having trouble.

All the code and test data is here: https://github.com/jmerkow/vtk_itk_rotate

Here are the relavent parts:

```
import SimpleITK as sitk
import vtk
import numpy as np
def rotate_img(img, rotation_center=None, theta_x=0,theta_y=0, theta_z=0, translation=(0,0,0), interp=sitk.sitkLinear, pixel_type=None, default_value=None):
    if not rotation_center:
        rotation_center = np.array(img.GetOrigin())+np.array(img.GetSpacing())*np.array(img.GetSize())/2
    if default_value is None:
        default_value = img.GetPixel(0,0,0)
    pixel_type = img.GetPixelIDValue()

    rigid_euler = sitk.Euler3DTransform(rotation_center, theta_x, theta_y, theta_z, translation)
    return sitk.Resample(img, img, rigid_euler, interp, default_value, pixel_type)

def rotate_polydata(pd, rotation_center, theta_x=0,theta_y=0, theta_z=0, translation=(0,0,0)):
    rigid_euler = sitk.Euler3DTransform(rotation_center, -theta_x, -theta_y, -theta_z, translation)
    matrix = np.zeros([4,4])
    old_matrix=np.array(rigid_euler.GetMatrix()).reshape(3,3)
    matrix[:3,:3] = old_matrix
    matrix[-1,-1] = 1

    # to rotate about a center we first need to translate
    transform_t = vtk.vtkTransform()
    transform_t.Translate(-rotation_center)
    transformer_t = vtk.vtkTransformPolyDataFilter()
    transformer_t.SetTransform(transform_t)
    transformer_t.SetInputData(pd)
    transformer_t.Update()

    transform = vtk.vtkTransform()
    transform.SetMatrix(matrix.ravel())

    transformer = vtk.vtkTransformPolyDataFilter()
    transformer.SetTransform(transform)
    transformer.SetInputConnection(transformer_t.GetOutputPort())
    transformer.Update()

    # translate back
    transform_t2 = vtk.vtkTransform()
    transform_t2.Translate(rotation_center)
    transformer_t2 = vtk.vtkTransformPolyDataFilter()
    transformer_t2.SetTransform(transform_t2)
    transformer_t2.SetInputConnection(transformer.GetOutputPort())
    transformer_t2.Update()

    return transformer_t2.GetOutputDataObject(0)

datafn = 'test.mha'
polydata_file = 'test.vtp'
reader = vtk.vtkXMLPolyDataReader()
reader.SetFileName(polydata_file)
reader.Update()
pd = reader.GetOutput()

img = sitk.ReadImage(datafn)
seg = pd_to_itk_image(pd, img)
rotation_center = np.array(img.GetOrigin())+np.array(img.GetSpacing())*np.array(img.GetSize())/2
thetas = [0, 50]
thetas = [0, 50]
for theta_x in thetas:
    for theta_y in thetas:
        for theta_z in thetas:
            theta_xr = theta_x/180.*np.pi
            theta_yr = theta_y/180.*np.pi
            theta_zr = theta_z/180.*np.pi
            img_rot=rotate_img(img, theta_z=theta_zr, theta_y=theta_yr, theta_x=theta_xr)
            seg_rot=rotate_img(seg, theta_z=theta_zr, theta_y=theta_yr, theta_x=theta_xr, interp=sitk.sitkNearestNeighbor, default_value=0)
            pd_rot = rotate_polydata(pd, rotation_center, theta_z=theta_zr, theta_y=theta_yr, theta_x=theta_xr)
            seg_pd_rot = pd_to_itk_image(pd_rot, img_rot)
            mse = ((sitk.GetArrayFromImage(seg_pd_rot)-sitk.GetArrayFromImage(seg_rot))**2.).mean()

            print theta_x, theta_y, theta_z, mse

#this outputs for this particular volume:
#0 0 0 mse: 0.0
#0 0 50 mse: 50.133369863 visually about the same
#0 50 0 mse: 25.2197787166 visually about the same
#0 50 50 mse: 863.588476181 visually totally different
#50 0 0 mse: 20.4021692276 visually about the same
#50 0 50 mse: 546.699844301 visually totally different
#50 50 0 mse: 662.337975204 visually totally different
#50 50 50 mse: 339.220945537 visually totally different
```

This code rotates a binary volume generated from the polydata, and performs the same rotation operation on the polydata then generates a binary volume from that. I would expect these two results to be (approximately) the same, however, what I am getting is two completely different rotations if I rotate around more than one axis.
This is puzzling to me since I am taking the transformation matrix from one and applying it directly to the other.

How can I setup these transforms such that the two operations perform the same transformations? And why do we end up with different results?

Comment: This example might be helpful: https://itk.org/Wiki/ITK/Examples/WishList/IO/itkVtkImageConvertDICOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to [Dženan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/276168/d%c5%beenan) for pointing me in the right direction.

The answer, in this case, was simple.  VTK and ITK use different row/column major formats for their matrix multiplication.  So the answer was simply to transpose the matrix before putting it into the vtkTransform.

Here is the new function.

```
def rotate_polydata(pd, rotation_center, theta_x=0,theta_y=0, theta_z=0):
    #I don't want to deal with translation
    translation=(0,0,0)
    rigid_euler = sitk.Euler3DTransform(rotation_center, theta_x, theta_y, theta_z, translation)
    matrix = np.zeros([4,4])
    old_matrix=np.array(rigid_euler.GetMatrix()).reshape(3,3)
    matrix[:3,:3] = old_matrix
    matrix[-1,-1] = 1
    #ITK and VTK use different orders.
    matrix= matrix.T

    # to rotate about a center we first need to translate
    transform_t = vtk.vtkTransform()
    transform_t.Translate(-rotation_center)
    transformer_t = vtk.vtkTransformPolyDataFilter()
    transformer_t.SetTransform(transform_t)
    transformer_t.SetInputData(pd)
    transformer_t.Update()

    transform = vtk.vtkTransform()
    transform.SetMatrix(matrix.ravel())
    transform.Translate(translation)
    transform.PostMultiply()

    transformer = vtk.vtkTransformPolyDataFilter()
    transformer.SetTransform(transform)
    transformer.SetInputConnection(transformer_t.GetOutputPort())
    transformer.Update()

    # translate back
    transform_t2 = vtk.vtkTransform()
    transform_t2.Translate(rotation_center)
    transformer_t2 = vtk.vtkTransformPolyDataFilter()
    transformer_t2.SetTransform(transform_t2)
    transformer_t2.SetInputConnection(transformer.GetOutputPort())
    transformer_t2.Update()

    return transformer_t2.GetOutputDataObject(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The order of Euler angles matters for the final result [[Wikipedia]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Rotation_matrix). Also, matrix pre-multiplying has reversed order to post-multiplying [[vtkTransform]](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkTransform.html). Try calling `vtkTransform::PostMultiply()` or reverse the order of transforms in your `rotate_polydata` function. This is easy to try.

If that does not solve it, look into how ITK is applying transforms in [ComputeOffset](https://github.com/hinerm/ITK/blob/master/Modules/Core/Transform/include/itkMatrixOffsetTransformBase.hxx#L724-L745), [TransformPoint](https://github.com/hinerm/ITK/blob/master/Modules/Core/Transform/include/itkMatrixOffsetTransformBase.hxx#L177-L186) and [ComputeMatrix](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITK/blob/master/Modules/Core/Transform/include/itkEuler3DTransform.hxx#L270-L279), and how VTK does it in [vtkLinearTransformPoint](https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/blob/master/Common/Transforms/vtkLinearTransform.cxx#L29-L44). That should explain the differences in behavior and provide clue as to how to achieve the same transforms.

Comment: Shouldn't the order not matter since I am taking the matrix from one and putting it into the other?  It's not calculating the matrix, its being provided.

Comment: Also this does not explain why it works when only rotating around one axis but not more.

Comment: In VTK case, you are supplying negative angles to sitk.Euler3DTransform, so you don't get out quite the same matrix. You might be mixing row major/column major between ITK and VTK, and that maybe works with negative angle for one angle, but not for more.

I have setup for debugging C++ code, not Python code.